# Tensorflow Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I declare my variable like this:

```
x = tf.Variable([len(_ELEMENT_LIST), 4], dtype=tf.float32)
```

I get the following error:

```
E0622 20:04:25.241938   21886 app.py:544] Top-level exception: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'input_layer/concat' (op: 'ConcatV2') with input shapes: [5], [5,1], [5,1], [].
E0622 20:04:25.252672   21886 app.py:545] Traceback (most recent call last):
```

When I do it like this:

```
x = tf.get_variable("x", [len(_ELEMENT_LIST), 4])
```

It works

I'm trying to compute Tensors using concat.

```
tf.concat([
        x, features["y"],
        features["z"]
    ], 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x = tf.Variable([len(_ELEMENT_LIST), 4], dtype=tf.float32)
```

the first parameter of `tf.Variable` is the initial value of the variable, so in the upper statement `x` is a Variable with value `[len(_ELEMENT_LIST), 4]`, and it's rank of shape is 1.

```
x = tf.get_variable("x", [len(_ELEMENT_LIST), 4])
```

the second parameter of `tf.get_variable` is the shape of Variable, so the rank of shape of Variable X is 2.